# Grab Parameters From URL Using HTML Only [For Typeform Embedding]

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, embed, typeform

A quick question.

```
<html> <head> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"> <title>Re-Imagining Business Models</title> <style type="text/css"> html{ margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; } iframe{ position: absolute; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; top:0; border:0; } </style> </head> <body> <iframe id="typeform-full" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://f03.typeform.com/to/AAAAAA?cl=xxxxx"></iframe> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://embed.typeform.com/embed.js"></script> </body> </html>
```

If you can see the cl=xxxxx, I need the xxxxx to be changed based on the parameters entered in the website.

from example:

www.mywebsite.com/formpage?cl=123121

The iframe will run this website: https://f03.typeform.com/to/AAAAAA?cl=123121

Is it possible using only HTML? because I'm working on Wordpress and don't know much what I can do in it other than builders and editing an HTML.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using [Typeform Embed API](https://developer.typeform.com/embed)

You can see a [working example](https://tf-embed-with-params.glitch.me?utm_source=stackoverflow_question) I made on Glitch

You can edit [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tf-embed-with-params).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Include Typeform Embed SDK in your HTML
2. Extract parameters from URL

   `let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);`
3. Reconstruct your form URL

   `var url = "https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.typeform.com/to/YOUR_TYPEFORM_ID";
   url += "?utm_source=" + params.get('utm_source');`
4. Display form in a target `div`

   `const embedElement = document.querySelector('.target-dom-node');
   window.typeformEmbed.makeWidget(
     embedElement,
     url, 
     {
       hideHeaders: true,
       hideFooter: true,
     }
   );`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I have installed Typeform SDK in Django. But can you help to use Template tag to use typeform sdk as suggest from https://pypi.org/project/django-typeform/ docs.