# Passing URL parameter in iframe issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, typeform

ser goes to http://yoursite.com/your-typeform-page?code=1 using a browser, that page needs to add a IFRAME with url as data-url=https://yoursite.typeform.com/to/U5aOQR?code=1

I want to pass url parameter as input to iFrame.

```html
<script>
 queryString = window.location.search;
var urlParams  = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
var code = urlParams.get('code')

 </script>

  <div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://yoursite.typeform.com/to/U5aOQR?code"+ code 
 style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
<script> (function() { var qs,js,q,s,d=document,gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm", b="https://embed.typeform.com/"; if(!gi.call(d,id)) { js=ce.call(d,"script"); js.id=id; js.src=b+"embed.js"; q=gt.call(d,"script")[0]; q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) } })() </script>

 </div>
```

Basically I want to pass value of code from line 4 to input as string in line 9.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768860/grab-parameters-from-url-using-html-only-for-typeform-embedding/52772649#52772649).

You can see a [working example](https://tf-embed-with-params.glitch.me?utm_source=stackoverflow_question) I made on Glitch

You can edit [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tf-embed-with-params).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Include Typeform Embed SDK in your HTML
2. Extract parameters from URL

   `let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);`
3. Reconstruct your form URL

   ```
   url += "?utm_source=" + params.get('utm_source');
   ```
4. Display form in a target `div`

   ````
   window.typeformEmbed.makeWidget(
     embedElement,
     url, 
     {
       hideHeaders: true,
       hideFooter: true,
     }
   );```
   ````

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I have installed Typeform SDK in Django. But can you help to use Template tag to use typeform sdk as suggest from pypi.org/project/django-typeform docs.

Comment: I am getting `TemplateSyntaxError at /wfhApp/survey/
'sekizai_tags'` is not a registered tag library