# AttributeError while using typeform sdk to pass url parameter to class

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I am using Django. I have pip installed typeform sdk using https://pypi.org/project/django-typeform/

I wanted Pass URL parameter in iframe issue as mentioned [Passing URL parameter in iframe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052520/passing-url-parameter-in-iframe-issue)

I tried using following https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tf-embed-with-params?path=README.md:1:0

Traceback:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'RequestContext' object has no attribute 'META'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext

def survey(request):
    return render(RequestContext(request),'wfhApp/survey.html')
```

And my html page is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load django_typeform %}
{% load sekizai_tags %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Hi there!</h1>
    <div class="target-dom-node" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
    <script src="https://embed.typeform.com/embed.js"></script>

    <script src="/survey/script.js"></script>
    {% typeforms_embed 'https://theother2thirds.typeform.com/to/hNZW30' 'New typeform' '{"hideHeaders": true, "hideFooter": true}' %}

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us installed apps and relevant code to your problem

Comment: @iklinac Please check i have added the required view.

Comment: where do you load sekizai_tags

Comment: @iklinac I haven't load sekizai_tags. I don't know where to load it.

Comment: You use them somewhere in your project search for sekizai_tags

Comment: @iklinac, Please check i have added traceback.

Comment: It say **Error during template rendering** In template `C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django_typeform\templates\django_typeform\typeform_embed.html`, error at line 1

Answer (score 0):

It does seem that this package uses `sekizai_tags` but it does not list sekizai as requirement anymore

old installation [docs](https://github.com/redapesolutions/django-typeform/blob/518f2c9519ef21e391e4e280645a43e853a10117/docs/installation.rst)

> django_typeform requires django-sekizai to be installed (should happen
>   automatically in the above instructions). Sekizai is used to position
>   javascript elements at the ebnd of the HTML body.

You should probably add [django_sekizai](https://github.com/divio/django-sekizai)

Comment: Can you help me out to add django_sekizai. As I am new to Django.

Comment: How do i use `django.template.RequestContext` when rendering your templates.

My views.py

`from django.shortcuts import render`
`def survey(request):`
   `return render(request,'wfhApp/survey.html')`

Comment: I have already added `‘sekizai’` to `INSTALLED_APPS` `sekizai.context_processors.sekizai` to your `TEMPLATES['OPTIONS']['context_processors']`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext

Comment: I have updated my question settings.py, views.py, and update error i am getting.

Comment: Please let me know if there is anything i am missing here.

Comment: have you installed package at all -> pip install django_sekizai

Comment: I have just pip install django_sekizai. And I have update views.py and Error that i am getting. Please check and let me know if there is something i am missing. Thanks @iklinac