# I am getting AttributeError in RequestContext in DJango

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I wanted Pass URL parameter in iframe issue as mentioned [Passing URL parameter in iframe issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052520/passing-url-parameter-in-iframe-issue)

I tried using following https://glitch.com/edit/#!/tf-embed-with-params?path=README.md:1:0

Traceback:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'RequestContext' object has no attribute 'META'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext

def survey(request):
    return render(RequestContext(request),'wfhApp/survey.html')
```

And my html page is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load django_typeform %}
{% load sekizai_tags %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">

  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Hi there!</h1>
    <div class="target-dom-node" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
    <script src="https://embed.typeform.com/embed.js"></script>

    <script src="/survey/script.js"></script>
    {% typeforms_embed 'https://theother2thirds.typeform.com/to/hNZW30' 'New typeform' '{"hideHeaders": true, "hideFooter": true}' %}

    </body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from wfhApp import views

app_name = 'wfhApp'

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^survey/$',views.survey, name='survey'),
]
```

Comment: Can you provide more of the traceback detail and your `urls.py` file?

Comment: @Tom, Please check i have just added `urls.py`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're wrapping the `request` inside of a `RequestContext` object, which is incorrect for [the `render()` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).

The `render()` function will build the `RequestContext` object for you, so it expects the `request` and any extra context variables as arguments.

Instead, just pass the request directly to the `render()` function:

```py
def survey(request):
    return render(request, 'wfhApp/survey.html')
```

Comment: After using render function I am getting. `Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 
You must enable the 'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai' template context processor or use 'sekizai.context.SekizaiContext' to render your templates.`

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar that's a separate question. It sounds like you need to add the sekizai context processor in `settings.py`: https://django-sekizai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuration

Comment: But I have already added django-sekizai. But it require to use `django.template.RequestContext` when rendering your templates. So I am not getting it how to render that way.